# Save a new Word Document for each row in Excel

Tags: excel, automation, ms-word

I have an Excel file with a list of names as follows:

```
*--------------------------------------*
| Last, First Middle | email@site.edu  |
*--------------------------------------*
```

All email addresses are "@site.edu"

I have a Word file like this

```
Dear <name>,
...
```

Is there a way to automatically save a copy of the Word document with the name cell inserted over  and save the file as "email" where "email" is the email address without site.edu?

I would also like to change  to be First Middle Last, but I can handle that by saving the Excel as .CSV and using a text editor with regular expressions.  I just don't know enough about the capabilities of Office to know if this is possible to automate.

Comment: Will you then be emailing the content of these files?

Comment: I need to email them all to one person to print them. Not emailing them to the addresses in the Excel sheet though.

Comment: If they're going to be printed out, why do they need to be separate files?  It sounds like maybe you just need to use Word's mail merge feature, which will allow you to use the Excel list as a source file for the salutation names and will create a personalized letter/document for each row.  They could then print the whole merged document.

Comment: I'm not the one printing them. It is getting sent to a department to handle mailing them to individuals, I just need documents with each person's name. The filename being the email was just a convenience. Anyway, I think Mail Merge is what I wanted and was hoping someone would point me to. You can add an answer and I would accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to use Word's mail merge feature, which will allow you to use the Excel list as a source file for the salutation names and will create a personalized letter/document for each row. They could then print the whole merged document.

Answer (score -1):

you can do alot with JScript, obviously only targeting Windows/IE. You can access your documents via IE too. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8(v=vs.85).aspx this link has a function for manipulating an Excel document, there's also a section for Word. http://www.thescriptlibrary.com/Default.asp?Action=Display&Level=Category3&ScriptLanguage=VBScript&Category1=Microsoft%20Office&Category2=Microsoft%20Excel&Title=Add%20Formatted%20Data%20to%20a%20Spreadsheet  i'm sure you can put them together into what ya need. sorry for not doing it for ya, i hate opening up Office documents.

Comment: Your answer is vague, as is the relevance of the links to the question.  And VBA is the obvious solution for automating Word and Excel.

Comment: You say: "there's also a section for Word" but I can't find it. Programmatically accessing Excel makes some sense to me, but I'd need a better example for Word.  Like Doug said, this is a bit vague (I don't need the full code, but give me something)

Comment: breadcrumbs Home > VBScript > Microsoft Office > Microsoft Excel so click on Office to go back then click on the Word link. sorry it wasn't more explanatory here it is http://www.thescriptlibrary.com/Default.asp?Action=Browse&Level=Category2&ScriptLanguage=VBScript&Category1=Microsoft%20Office&Category2=Microsoft%20Word